# Site for motorcycles on SE

Tags: support, area-51

I've been looking for a SE-site devoted to motorcycles. Sadly, I've only got hits on bikes (the sweaty kind) and mechanics/repairs.

Do I miss an obvious site (for people who don't like to sweat nor need to screw stuff)?!

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61379/motorcycles. Although, some would argue that motorcycles are just as sweaty as bikes, especially in the summer when wearing a full set of leathers.

Comment: At the moment, there is no dedicated Motorcycles SE site. I'm curious what kind of questions you want to ask about motorcycles that wouldn't fall under the umbrella of "mechanics/repairs"; could you elaborate?

Comment: [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorcycle) is probably the best bet, but the topic does seem focused on repairs. See [Regarding off-topic questions and the divide between “mechanics” and “motor vehicles.”](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/39/4260) and [Are driving questions on-topic?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1/4260)

Comment: @Pops Driving techniques - I need to ask about e.g. the traction on the white stripes at pedestrian crossings during rain.

Comment: @Matt Hail to that! When one's going over 100 Viking speed unit (65 Yankee speed units) everything feels nice. As soon as one stops at the red lights, the sprinkles all over one's body start squirting like crazy. Not nice.   :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you did not miss an obvious site.

There is a [motorcycles proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61379/motorcycles) on area 51, but it has not yet gotten to a stage where it has enough followers to be put into a private beta.

You can also suggest your own proposal there - on whatever topic. It will need enough of a following to become a site though, as described in the area 51 [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

You can see all sites at [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites).